# Segmentation Fault on running a binary on heroku

Tags: heroku, executable

I have a binary file named `OTK.e` which I am executing programmatically using Node.js `child_process` module.

```js
const { execFile } = require('child_process');
const execute = () => new Promise((resolve) => {
    execFile(path.resolve(__dirname, './bin/OTK.e'), {
        cwd: path.resolve(__dirname, './bin'),
    }, (err, stdout) => {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
            reject(err);
        }
        resolve(stdout);
    });
});
```

This works fine when I run this locally on my Ubuntu 18.04.5. I have deployed this app to heroku and I cant get this to work there. I found this in the logs:

```sh
2021-07-19T14:48:55.432325+00:00 app[web.1]: Error: Command failed: /app/bin/OTK.e
2021-07-19T14:48:55.432334+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-07-19T14:48:55.432335+00:00 app[web.1]: at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:319:12)
2021-07-19T14:48:55.432335+00:00 app[web.1]: at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:375:28)
2021-07-19T14:48:55.432336+00:00 app[web.1]: at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1055:16)
2021-07-19T14:48:55.432336+00:00 app[web.1]: at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:288:5) {
2021-07-19T14:48:55.432337+00:00 app[web.1]: killed: false,
2021-07-19T14:48:55.432340+00:00 app[web.1]: code: null,
2021-07-19T14:48:55.432341+00:00 app[web.1]: signal: 'SIGSEGV',
2021-07-19T14:48:55.432341+00:00 app[web.1]: cmd: '/app/bin/OTK.e'
2021-07-19T14:48:55.432342+00:00 app[web.1]: }
```

The process seems to be terminating with a segmentation fault. Any ideas what might be going on?

Comment: Where does this binary come from? How are you getting it onto Heroku? In general, binaries aren't portable. You'll need to make sure it's compiled for the target system, ideally by building it _on_ Heroku as part of your deployment.

Comment: Thanks for the response @Chris. 
Oh I see, I was told this came from compiling some C/C++ code, but I dont have access to the code itself. Does this mean I need to compile the code on heroku and not simply upload the executable?

Comment: Can you get access to the source code? Is it something generally available, or something built specifically for this purpose? Depending on what it is the best bet might be to build it from source, to install it as a package using an `Aptfile`, or something else. If you're building it elsewhere it will need to be compatible with Ubuntu Linux since that's what [Heroku's stacks are based on](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/stack#stack-support-details).

Comment: @Chris The source code is confidential, it cannot be shared is what I have been told. I was also told that the source code was compiled on redhat linux. Yes I have gone through that page before and I thought it should most probably work fine since I was able to run it on Ubuntu 18.